# mysql calculation based on the conditions into a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a t_personne table. 
I encodes a general form for each person. 
I also encodes a table "interview" (t_entretien) a presence per project (proj_id). 
For the project, it can have multiple actions. 
The project action "RAE" are encoded: 2-01.01, 2-02.01, 2-02.02 ...... 2-03.01, 2-03.02, etc.

I have a following calculation rule: A unit is equal to 2 actions from two different categories into the actions encoded. 
For example, a person with one action 2-02.01 and 2-03.01 with 2-03.04 actions will only be counted as one unit.
A person who has 4 shares of 2-03 types will not count.
I have to calculate the total number of units.

I started thinking:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1
FROM (SELECT t_entretien.id
      FROM t_entretien 
      INNER JOIN
      t_action on t_action.cact_caction = t_entretien.ent_id
      GROUP BY t_entretien.id
      HAVING(COUNT(DISTINCT t_action.cact_caction) > 1)) AS derivedtbl_1
```

Here is a little FIDDLE http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c831/1

Thanks for all !

EDITION

The context is the following.

I get a person (t_personne) and using a form I introduce general data.

This person, I enrolled into a project (t_projet) at the time of the interview (t_entretien). 
During the interview, I realize actions. 
Every actions are specific projects (t_action). 
For the project, including the "cact_code" is 2, I chose different actions encoded (see table t_codeaction).

My problem is the following. I must calculate the number of actions based on a formula that is imposed on me: one unit = 2 actions belonging to different categories. Categories are identified as follows (t_codeaction): 2-01 this category has only one action (2-01.01), the following category includes 4 actions 2-02 and 2-03 in the third category includes 12 actions, etc.
Imagine that the person "ent_id" = 8105 received four actions, one in the category 2-01.01 and 2-03 in the other 3. It is one and only one unit under the rule as it has received at least two actions two different categories. 3 actions in the 2-03 category account for an action. Thus, the person whose "ent_id" = 8114 received only 3 actions of the same class 2-03, this unit is 0.

Comment: I have no idea what you're after.

Comment: Each action is encoded according to the principle 2-01.01,2-01.02... 2-02.01, 2-02.02, etc. If the person has received only one type of action that does not count (one type is 2-01, another is 2-02, one more 2-03).

Comment: That's great. I still have no idea what you have or what you're after. If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry he already added a fiddle; please just add a desired result table sample

Comment: @guido - I know, but it included `t_personne` and `t_codeaction` tables which both seemed irrelevant :-(

Comment: @Strawberry that's right; so, leerickx, you are asking us to fix your schema, or write your query?

Comment: Write a query. It is to hard for me now ;-) and thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am probably wildguessing because the question is bad described, but anyway, something like this?

```
SELECT id as entretiedId, count(*)/2 as units from
 (SELECT t_entretien.id, SUBSTRING(t_action.cact_caction,1,4) as CATEGORY, COUNT(*) 
  FROM t_entretien 
  INNER JOIN
  t_action on t_action.ent_id = t_entretien.ent_id
  GROUP BY t_entretien.id, CATEGORY) as t_derived
GROUP BY id having count(distinct category) > 1
```

The derived table counts actions, but with one row per ent per category. then the outer `group by` counts the subactions per category, and divides by two for calculating the units.

fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c831/22/0

Comment: Thanks. Let me try in a few minutes. I say you what and I'll try to describe better and clarify my question.

Comment: Thanks guido for your test :) 
I try to clarify. I re-edited my question.

Comment: given your edited question, the output of the above query is correct.

Comment: Your query actually works well.
Tell me, I added an action for a person. If you divide by 2 then the unit is 1.5, I should still have 2 units for that person because it 2 times 2 actions from different categories: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/948b7/1

Comment: change it like this: `SELECT id as entretiedId, CEIL(count(*)/2) as units from ...`

Comment: You have already helped me ... a big thank you ... I'll still have to specify the start rule. For example, a specific category of 2-05 type will be counted only as a single unit if it occurs 5 times, the less it will not be counted, it will be 10 times 2 units, etc.